# Can't get records to show with date filter, when there is no related records

Tags: sql, postgresql

Not sure exactly how to make this work. I have multiple related tables. Users, Clients, Task, and Timerecords. What im trying to accomplish is for the user, show all clients that they have, and sum all the hours that have been spent on that client for the current month.

it should show the client even if there are no time records in the current month.

as I built out the query in steps... It worked until I added the where date is greater than. So this worked (it showed all clients regardless if there was time records, but it summed the hours regardless of the date.

```
SELECT Clients.company_name, 
       Clients.logo, 
       Clients.id, 
       SUM(Timerecords.manual_input_hours) as hours_spent_on_client
FROM Clients
INNER JOIN
Mapping_User_To_Clients
ON Clients.id = Mapping_User_To_Clients.client_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Timerecords
    ON Clients.id = Timerecords.client_id
WHERE Mapping_User_To_Clients.user_id = 5
GROUP BY Clients.company_name, 
         Clients.logo, 
         Clients.id;
```

When I add the where date is greater than the first of the current month, It only returns the clients that have timerecords with hours completed. The clients with no timerecords yet, disappear. I'm stumped at how to make this work (I hardcoded the user_id(5) and date(2021-06-01) for testing the query, these will be variables).

```
SELECT Clients.company_name, 
       Clients.logo, 
       Clients.id, 
       SUM(Timerecords.manual_input_hours) as hours_spent_on_client
FROM Clients
INNER JOIN
Mapping_User_To_Clients
ON Clients.id = Mapping_User_To_Clients.client_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Timerecords
    ON Clients.id = Timerecords.client_id
WHERE Mapping_User_To_Clients.user_id = 5 and Timerecords.time_start >= '2021-06-01'
GROUP BY Clients.company_name, 
         Clients.logo, 
         Clients.id;
```

Comment: Put the `and Timerecords.time_start >= '2021-06-01'` in the `ON` clause of the LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I strongly recommend table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.

Second, you need to move the filtering condition on the last table to the `ON` clause.  Otherwise the `LEFT JOIN` turns into an `INNER JOIN` (that is, `NULL` values are filtered out):

```
SELECT cl.company_name, cl.logo, cl.id, 
       SUM(tr.manual_input_hours) as hours_spent_on_client
FROM Clients cl JOIN
     Mapping_User_To_Clients utc
     ON cl.id = utc.client_id LEFT JOIN
     Timerecords tr
     ON cl.id = tr.client_id AND
        tr.time_start >= '2021-06-01'
WHERE utc.user_id = 5 
GROUP BY cl.company_name, cl.logo, cl.id;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I really like that tip regarding using table aliases as well.